# Are there publicly available run-off data for Africa?

Tags: data, hydrology, africa

I was wondering if there are good publicly available dataset for surface run-off (water)?

I have a rough idea that surface run-off should be some function of rain-fall and soil infiltration/absorption etc. My question is whether there is some reputable dataset for Africa or globally.

I did a preliminary search, but most datasets that say "rainfall/run-off" are actually rain-fall data. And I can't find a run-off dataset for download.

I have STRM DEM data, and have processed the terrain using ArcHydro. What I am really looking for is something that combines rainfall and soil absorption etc, to give runoff estimates.

Comment: Africa is a very large area comprising of 50+ countries. How about you narrow down your search area to a country or region of Africa.

Comment: @jonathanw I am specifically interested in West (and Central) Africa.

Answer (score 3):

Ok I know of two products that may help you.

1. This [site](http://www.creaf.uab.es/miramon/mmr/examples/miombo/docs/database/hydro30s/index.htm) gives all the grunt work for the hydrologiclly
   correct layers you would require to conduct such an analysis.
2. The Open-source Water Observation and Information System (WOIS) is now
   active in Africa. Is is compiled using open-source GIS ([link](http://www.tiger-net.org/index.php?id=12))
   and includes modules for [TSS](http://www.tiger-net.org/index.php?id=16).

It is not a project for beginners and Africa is rather large so you should start with a singular basin but conceptually much of these data now exist designed for use in FOSS GIS.

Comment: Thanks for the info. They could be useful for computing the runoff, but I can't find a run-off layer.

Comment: You will not find a runoff layer for Africa. You will have to make it.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you have check this out ?

http://www.diva-gis.org/ ?

http://www.diva-gis.org/gdata

How about this ?

http://www.infrastructureafrica.org/documents/tools/list/arcgis-shape-files

This might help you to browse around in Africa.

http://wikimapia.org/#lang=en&lat=12.983148&lon=9.755859&z=3&m=b&search=Africa